# illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions (JBPM)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jbpm

I have an application that use JBPM (5.4). It executes several workitem actions that supposed to run on same transaction. In each action it creates an entityManager.
When I try to run one of the process i get the *illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions* exception.

Is there a way to merge the object between sessions? I have no control on the session/transaction inside the jbpm process.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

javax.transaction has Synchronization interface which in this case I think you should use it.

this code comes from integration between seam/Hibernate and jbpm.

```
public class ManagedJbpmContext implements Synchronization
{
   private static final LogProvider log = Logging.getLogProvider(ManagedJbpmContext.class);

   private JbpmContext jbpmContext;
   private boolean synchronizationRegistered;

   @Create
   public void create() throws NamingException, RollbackException, SystemException
   {
      jbpmContext = Jbpm.instance().getJbpmConfiguration().createJbpmContext();
      assertNoTransactionManagement();
      log.debug( "created seam managed jBPM context");
   }

   private void assertNoTransactionManagement()
   {
      DbPersistenceServiceFactory dpsf = (DbPersistenceServiceFactory) jbpmContext.getJbpmConfiguration()
            .getServiceFactory(Services.SERVICENAME_PERSISTENCE);
      if ( dpsf.isTransactionEnabled() )
      {
         throw new IllegalStateException("jBPM transaction management is enabled, disable in jbpm.cfg.xml");
      }
   }

   @Unwrap
   public JbpmContext getJbpmContext() throws NamingException, RollbackException, SystemException
   {
      joinTransaction();
      return jbpmContext;
   }

   private void joinTransaction() throws SystemException
   {
      UserTransaction transaction = Transaction.instance();

      if ( !transaction.isActiveOrMarkedRollback() )
      {
         throw new IllegalStateException("JbpmContext may only be used inside a transaction");
      }

      if ( !synchronizationRegistered && !Lifecycle.isDestroying() && transaction.isActive() )
      {
         jbpmContext.getSession().isOpen();
         try //TODO: what we really want here is if (!cmt)
         {
            transaction.registerSynchronization(this);
         }
         catch (UnsupportedOperationException uoe)
         {
            jbpmContext.getSession().getTransaction().registerSynchronization(this);
         }
         synchronizationRegistered = true;
      }
   }

   public void beforeCompletion()
   {
      log.debug( "flushing seam managed jBPM context" );

      jbpmContext.getSession().flush();
      log.debug( "done flushing seam managed jBPM context" );
   }

   public void afterCompletion(int status) 
   {
      synchronizationRegistered = false;
      if ( !Contexts.isEventContextActive() )
      {
         //in calls to MDBs and remote calls to SBs, the 
         //transaction doesn't commit until after contexts
         //are destroyed, so wait until the transaction
         //completes before closing the session
         //on the other hand, if we still have an active
         //event context, leave it open
         closeContext();
      }
   }



   private void closeContext()
   {
      log.debug( "destroying seam managed jBPM context" );
      jbpmContext.close();
      log.debug( "done destroying seam managed jBPM context" );
   }

}
```